# How to make a http request to server that doesn't need reply?

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest, fetch

Should client always get a reply on it's request?

I need to make an HTTP request from client to server (with fetch, if i can). 
Server on this request do something.
Client doesn't need an reply at all.

How can i do it?

Now i from client do:

```
 fetch('/test/1', {
    method: 'POST'
  })
```

But get error:
POST

```
https://localhost:3000/test/1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Comment: You'll always get a response (that's how HTTP works), however you can discard it or never use it

Comment: You have to wait for the reply, that is part of the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

Symmary. You always need to reply to client, you can just send 204 code reply from server.